# Align elements in center ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I hava a code, inside it's a loop that output me a numbers.Something like this :

```
<div *ngFor="let x of y.x" >
```

now the output is here :

```
<h5 class="centeredX " *ngIf="x.link == ''">{{x.x}}<span *ngIf="x.isZ == 1"> <sup>3D</sup></span></h5>
```

So how can align on the same line all elements?My output is always something like this :

```
1
2
3
4
```

I want this,also centerd in the middle of the page :

```
1 2 3 4
```

I used Ionic 2 and angular 2.

Comment: Open the page with that output in Chrome, open the inspector (F12), go to the elements tab and expand as necessary. Then post the rendered HTML to get a better look at what's going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding styles will align the items. You can use class to style or use inline styles as below.

```
 <div *ngFor="let x of y.x" style:"display:inline-flex">
    ...
    </div>
```